# Column does not exist in sql

Tags: java, sql

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'movie_borr' not found.
```

I am very certain that this column exists in the database I created.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select movie_id, movie_name, movie_dateBorrowed from movie_tbl where movie_borr = '"+userUserID+"'");
                if(rs.next()){
                    String moviebo = rs.getString("movie_borr");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, moviebo);
                }
```

Comment: movie_borr is not selected in the query, is just part of the condition. add it to the select clause, if you need it (though you already send it as a param...)

Comment: @wxyz make it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you name a column in `getString`, that column must be listed in the `select` clause.  Add `movie_borr` to the list of columns after `select`.

**EDIT** Sorry, @wxyz - I didn't see that you got there first.  If you post your answer, I'll delete mine!